# How do I make pytest fail fast as a user level configuration?

Tags: pytest

I want to always run pytest in a fail-fast mode like `--maxfail=1`, regardless the code repository I am testing.

Mainly I am using for a config item which can be setup as an environment variable or a user homedir config file which would make it fail fast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following environment variable should do the job:

```
export PYTEST_ADDOPTS="-x"
```

More info:

- [How to change command line options defaults](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/customize.html#adding-default-options)
- [Failure options](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html#stopping-after-the-first-or-n-failures)